# Openstack newton - VM are slow

Tags: performance, virtual-machine, openstack

I host an Openstack Newton in High Availability passive mode.

But I have an issue with the speed. In fact my VMs are very slow. 
An "apt-get update" takes 5 minutes and I have a good network bandwith.

Someone could help me to identify the problem please ?

Thanks you :)

Comment: It would help if you can share the networking details also - are you using provider network or floating IP, etc ?

Comment: I am using floating IPs AND Provider network. But VMs are slow in both configuration

Comment: Are you using 10G networking without configuring jumbo frames (MTU 9000+), or possibly jumbo frames are enabled through some of the hops. If you are using 10G then there are settings in Neutron to help configure the virtual network interfaces with the correct MTU. The defaults are going to be 1500. If you aren't using 10G networking then you could also try lowering the MTU of one of the instances to see if it helps. Lower it to around 1454 and see if the traffic speeds up, for troubleshooting. I wouldn't suggest lowering the MTU as a fix.